# How to restore Contacts from a filesystem backup?

Tags: backup, contacts, restore, providers

I make filesystem backups of `/data/` and am trying to restore my contacts.
Contacts appear to be stored in `/data/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.contacts/`, specifically its `database/contacts2.db`.

Manually restoring this directory however does not appear to work.
The data is 1:1 the same but, upon opening the contacts app, all contacts are wiped from the db.

How can I restore contacts from a filesystem backup such that they're not wiped by Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to restore contacts (and other providers for that matter it seems), you must restore *all* content `com.android.provider.*` directories under both `/data/data/` and `/data/user_de/0/`.

When I do that, all my contacts are in the contacts app as they should be.
SMS messages, call history etc. are also restored.

(It is possible there is a specific subset of directories that are sufficient aswell but I didn't pursue this further as you'd usually want SMS etc. to also be restored, so might as well restore all content providers.)